# Stuck in a loop using file management in C

Tags: c, file, loops, gcc, file-management

The program is:

Two files DATA1 and DATA2 contain sorted lists of integers/ Write a program to produce a third file DATA which holds a single sorted, merged list of these two lists. Use command line arguments to specify the file names.

```
#include<stdio.h>

//Two files DATA1 and DATA2 contain sorted lists of integers/ Write a program to produce a third file DATA which holds a single sorted, merged list of these two lists. Use command line arguments to specify the file names.

void sort(FILE*, FILE*, FILE*);

main()
{
    FILE *f1, *f2, *f;
    int i;

    f1=fopen("DATA1", "w");    //To set the sorted integers in file f1
    for(i=0;i<=10; i=i+2)
    putw(i, f1);
    fclose(f1);

    f2=fopen("DATA2", "w");    //To set the sorted integers in file f2
    for(i=1;i<=11; i=i+2)
        putw(i, f2);
    fclose(f2);

    printf("For first DATA:\n");    //To print the content of f1
    f1=fopen("DATA1", "r");
    while((i=getw(f1)) != EOF)
        printf("%d, ", i);
    fclose(f1);

    printf("\nFor second DATA:\n");    //To print the content of file f2
    f2=fopen("DATA2", "r");
    while((i=getw(f2)) != EOF)
        printf("%d, ", i);
    fclose(f2);

    sort(f1, f2, f);    //To sort the integers from f1 and f2 and merge the sorted into file f

    f=fopen("DATA", "r");    //To print the integers in file f
    while((i=getw(f)) != EOF)
        printf("%d, ", i);
    fclose(f);
}

void sort(FILE *d1, FILE *d2, FILE *d)
{
    int a, b;
    d1=fopen("DATA1", "r");
    d2=fopen("DATA2", "r");
    d=fopen("DATA", "w");
    a=getw(d1);
    b=getw(d2);
    for(;some condition;)
    {
        if(a>b)
        {
            int temp=a;
            a=b;
            b=temp;
            b=getw(d2);
            putw(a, d);
            b=getw(d2);
        }
        else
        {
            putw(a, d);
            a=getw(d1);
        }
    }
    fclose(d1);
    fclose(d2);
    fclose(d);
}
```

Now the program is compiled in gcc compiler by using the command "gcc file.c". After compiling when I run the program, it shows the content of file f1 but not the content of file f2. I seems as if it is stuck in a loop because Ctrl + D do not work. So I have to terminate the program.

The output is:

> For first DATA:
>   0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10,
>   For second DATA:
>   ^Z
>   [6]+  Stopped                 ./a.out

Now what is the problem here. I printed the integers of f2 in the same way I printed the integers of f1 but why is the problem only in file f2?

Comment: I hope you know Ctrl-Z doesn't terminate the program, it just pauses it.

Comment: `for(;some condition;)` is not real code.

Comment: @melpomene Now I know about the Ctrl-Z. Thanks. And I know that I shouldn't have put "some condition" but I did it to check if the program was working up to that point.

Comment: @manshu That makes no sense. Your code doesn't even compile.

Comment: @melpomene I made the infinite loop in my code :p

Comment: Compile with `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` then use the debugger `gdb`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should output:

```
For first DATA:
0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 
For second DATA:
1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11,
```

which is what you need. I suspect the error happens shortly after, and the output buffer is just not flushed in time, thus the data are kept there, and not being displayed in standard output (your screen most likely).

Change your code to:

```
printf("\nFor second DATA:\n");    //To print the content of file f2
f2=fopen("DATA2", "r");
while((i=getw(f2)) != EOF)
    printf("%d, ", i);
fclose(f2);

printf ("\n");
fflush(stdout);

sort(f1, f2, f);
```

to see what I mean. The newline flushes the output buffer itself, so you can use either approaches.